# How to go fullscreen in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, fullscreen, powershell-2.0

Is there a way of making powershell appear in fullscreen? Not only maximize it over the screen, but hiding the top-bar as well?

Also, since this is probably hard to do, how to maximize it according to current resolution?

Comment: You might find this ServerFault question to be of use: http://serverfault.com/questions/21367/setting-powershell-display-options-property

Comment: A-ha. Goodness. At least I can stretch it out, but the full screen shortcut does not do anything.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Right click the top bar and select properties. Then depending on your screen resolution select the appropriate size. (under the layout tab).

Comment: Wow, it's 2011 and you still cannot maximize a console window in a user-friendly way.

Comment: Windows 8 has full-screen mode for PowerShell when maximized. Apparently it has nothing tried to do with $host.Version=3. I upgraded PS in Windows 7 but still no full-screen mode. Nonetheless, you can use PS-ISE for full-screen experience in Windows 7.

Comment: I come from the future. Still not possible in 2016.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Yep, that won't be true. Windows 10 brings a new shell that supports it ;)
Oh, and it will come this year :D

Comment: @func0der this makes me a big liar but yay! anyways :D I really liked it.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin , you are not a liar. You just created an alternative timeline. You should know how dangerous time-travelling can be.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin, who built your time machine? In Windows 7, it's still not possible. In 2016.

Comment: Wow...and people seriously wonder why Windows is perceived as an inferior dev platform for anything but .NET?

Comment: I can confirm, still not possible in 2016.

Comment: Seems to be possible in 2017.  Hitting [Alt]+[Enter] goes full screen with no window title bar.  You still get a vertical scrollbar down the right side though.

Comment: Still not possible in Window 7 professional, service pack 1 ...2017 .. Wow!!

Comment: 2018 reporting in with windows 10. Alt+Enter and F11 both sometimes work and sometimes not. Usually they start working after the window has been open for a few minutes and has had a script or two run on it.

Comment: 2020 reporting back in time, its still not possible on Windows 8 Powershell.

Comment: @kbau In PowerShell 6, it will run, but only if there is a program running in the foreground (e.g. `pause`, then F11) but not in the shell itself.

Answer (score 65):

Try typing the following command:

```
mode 300
```

after the window opens

Comment: perfect solution, +1 for simplicity.

Comment: if you run a single monitor configuration the mode 300 command works fine. If you are using dual monitor it does not. I thus often use the wmic command then maximize the window and and exit command as a sequence to go in full screen.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this was possible. Wonder why I've been out of it for so long...oh wait, that's right: I've been using `bash` half the time and the other half getting `bash` to work in Windows :P Works great except the top-left corner of your window has to already be at the top-left part of your screen. It doesn't just re-position it for you.

Comment: ...except this also clears the console, so I had to re-run the build to get the output back... :(

Answer (score 35):

`ALT + ENTER` will full screen the powershell window in Windows 10

If this doesn't work right click the title bar > properties > options and make sure "Use Legacy console" is **unchecked**:

[image: powershell]

Comment: This is now the correct answer. Unchecking "Use legacy console" allows the window to be resized like any other.

Comment: Of course you'll have to go to the layout tab and reduce your height (probably to double-digits) to get rid of the scroll bar on the right-hand side.

Comment: Is there now way to simply maximize the window, keeping the title bar? EDIT: `Windows`+`Up` does the trick

Comment: Ok, thanks for this: I've my 4yo kid around, and I didn't know what was the key he touched as I was typing. I've missed like 15 minutes. Sigh...

Answer (score 11):

The trick to using PS in a modern fashion is to use a different type of terminal program. I use ConEmu as it is open-source and free.

Not only will it allow you to run the screen maximised, you can have several tabs, clear-type fonts, custom colours et cetera.

Together with the free 'Source Code Pro' font, it makes for a very nice PS environment.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Finally a console that can be maximized.

Answer (score 10):

Display Options -> Fullscreen, or ALT+ENTER should enter fullscreen mode.

Comment: although my system doesn't support fullscreen mode??

Comment: Where do you see those options?

Comment: This option is not available in Vista/Win7/2008/2008R2 with the introduction of the Desktop Window Manager and accelerated desktop composition via your graphics card.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a shortcut with

```
"%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe " -NoExit -Command "mode 300"
```

The **-NoExit** option will keep the console open after running the startup command, and the
**-Command** option of course runs the command on console startup.
Besides, if you're not an administrator or you're running Windows 8 (hence apps run as not privileged by default) you can setup your shortcut to run Powershell as administrator always.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff629472.aspx)

Comment: This option was already suggested 4 months ago by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667745/64046).

Comment: Yes but not as a shortcut, instead, as a command to be written after the console starts. I believe this way is more "permanent", if you will.

Answer (score 2):

If it would be sufficient to merely maximize your PowerShell window, you can simply add `-WindowStyle Maximized` to your PowerShell shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -WindowStyle Maximized
```