# Windows 10 Make Start full screen powershell command?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm looking for a powershell commandlet that changes the setting on "Make Start full screen"
Anyone know of one?

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking. what should go fullscreen? the PowerShell Window? if so check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197278/how-to-go-fullscreen-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to reference this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt431718(v=vs.85).aspx

and tailor it to your specific needs. It looks to be that since Windows 8/8.1 the Start Screen/Menu is configured in an XML format. That Technet article will explain how to export the layout, make the changes and then import it so that the changes are applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to start powershell in full screen. Add the **-WindowStyle maximized** to your exe call. This is how I start it:

1. "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -WorkingDirectory ~ **-WindowStyle maximized**
2. %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe **-WindowStyle maximized**