# Windows Powershell not showing anything but a blue screen; can't type in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Everytime I try to use Powershell, it just shows a blank blue screen with the blinking rectangle at top left corner of screen. I try the Ctrl+x then Ctrl+C, but that just closes Powershell (More specifically, Ctrl+c)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really and PowerShell specific thing and not really a PowerShell code issue., which is why we are here. So, this sort of question really should be on the SuperUser Q&A.

Anyway, since you are here.

Somehow you or someone have/has that window resized to where it is not usable. There are tricks on the web regarding how to resize those oddball windows. Yet, you can do this, start PowerShell from cmd.exe using maximize switch.

So, start cmd.exe and look at this discussion/answer.

> [How to go fullscreen in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197278/how-to-go-fullscreen-in-powershell)

```
powershell.exe -noexit -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Once maximize, just change the windows properties as normal so you don't have to do this.
Even if you could not see the consoelhost, you could have just used the PowerShell ISE or download and install Visual Studio Code (you'll need to add the Powershell extension), or install the Windows Terminal app (if you are on Windows 10) from the MS Store, to do your PowerShell stuff.